# How to change the path to JS .map files in Grunt & Coffee Script

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, gruntjs, relative-path

I have the following snippet in my gruntfile:

```
coffee: {
    dev: {
        options: {
            bare: true,
            sourceMap: true,
            sourceMapDir: 'grails-app/assets/javascripts/map/' 
        },
        expand: true,
        cwd: "grails-app/assets/javascripts/coffee/",
        src: [ "**/**.coffee" ],
        dest: "grails-app/assets/javascripts/js/",
        ext: ".js"
    }
}, ...
```

when it creates the .js files it attaches the following line to the file:

```
//# sourceMappingURL=../../../../../grails-app/assets/javascripts/map/Init.js.map
```

which results in 404 errors in js console

But
What I want to see is:

```
//# sourceMappingURL=assets/javascripts/map/Init.js.map
```

I can edit the actual coffee script module, but wanted to know if there is any other ways to change the relative path using Grunt